# multiline gtk entry in pygtk

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I know there is a PyGTK class for a single-line entry, but what about 
multi-line entries (like entering a description of an item)?
I've searched through the web, but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TextView is the widget used to edit multi-line text.